# With CSS, can the height of an element be a function of the width of the browser?

Tags: function, css, resize, height

ie changing as one resizes the browswer.

I'm trying to have a logo in the center of the top of my website grow or shrink as the window resizes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it's possible if the parent of the image relies on the width of the browser. You can make the width of the image into percentages.

http://jsfiddle.net/SGmRQ/

html:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://www.digitaleconomics.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/see-how-your-google-results-measure-up-with-google-grader-video-6b8bbb4b41.jpg" />
</div>
```

css:

```
div {
    width: 100%;
}
img {
    width: 50%;
}
```